# user.status always returns "offline"

Tags: discord.py

I know that `user.status` should be used to return the user status. But it always returns the status of offline, regardless of the fact that I or other participants change the status.
Code:

```py
@app_commands.command(name='user', description=f'Детальна інформація про користувача')
    async def user_(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.Member = None):
    ctx = await self.bot.get_context(interaction)# Don't pay attention to it
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.author
    print(user.status)
    global user_status
    user_status = None
    if user.status == discord.Status.online:
        user_status = "<:online:1038376483758030898>В мережі"
    elif user.status == discord.Status.offline or user.status == discord.Status.invisible:
        user_status = "<:ofline:1038376481774120970>Не в мережі"
    elif user.status == discord.Status.idle:
        user_status = "<:idle:1038376474958381056>Відійшов"
    elif user.status == discord.Status.dnd or user.status == discord.Status.do_not_disturb:
        user_status = "<:dnds:1048347246556626954>Не турбувати"
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

In another command (not a slash command), this status check is working properly. Intentions I have set up that
`bot = commands.Bot(commands.when_mentioned_or('.'), intents = discord.Intents.all())`.
And in the portal of the developers, too, seems to be right
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug that it shows up as offline everytime, but here's something you can do:

```
userstatus = interaction.guild.get_member(user.id).status
if userstatus == discord.Status.online:
    user_status = "<:online:1038376483758030898>В мережі"
#rest of your checks here
```

ps: You don't need `or user.status == discord.Status.do_not_disturb` and `or user.status == discord.Status.invisible` because they mean the same thing as `discord.Status.offline` and `discord.Status.dnd` respectively.

Comment: Thank you, this feature `interaction.guild.get_member(user.id)`  helped me