# Slash command gives incorrect value for member.status

Tags: python, discord.py

The following hybrid command gives varying results depending on if it is invoked as a commands.command or as a slash command:

```
@commands.hybrid_command()
async def test(self, ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send(f"Your status: {ctx.author.status}")
```

When invoked as !test, it correctly gives the member.status. However, when the command is invoked as a slash command, the result is always "offline".

Any slash command that I create cannot correctly determine member.status, and any commands.command() I create works correctly.

I have my intents set to discord.Intents.all(). I've tried resetting my permissions through the Discord Developer Portal, but I am mostly baffled as to why a normal command works perfectly and a slash command fails in the same scenario.

### Edit

Using the object that returns from `ctx.guild.get_member(ctx.author)` the `member.status` value works as intended from within a slash command. For whatever reason, it just seems that the member object passed from `ctx.author` in a slash command does not have the same functionality as it normally does.

Comment: I don't work with discord.py. However, I'm wondering if there should be any parameters in the decorator. Using the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=hybrid#discord.ext.commands.hybrid_command), should a `name` for the command be provided as a parameter?

Comment: What happens if you use [`raw_status`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.raw_status)?

Comment: @BlueRobin The decorator doesn't have any required parameters. In the docs, not including `name` will have the command default to the name of the function. Also, `raw_status` just gives the status value as a string, so it has the same results.

Comment: Looking at your edit, it may be a library issue. I would open an issue on their github. Also, you may want to add your edit as an answer to show that this has been resolved.

Comment: I haven't played around with hybrid commands before but could you do `ctx.interaction.user.status` when the `ctx.interaction is not None` and see what you get?

Comment: Yes, `interaction.user.status` always returns "offline". I'm not quite sure what's wrong but it's definitely not you. My hypothesis is that `interaction.user` returns a different object than `ctx.author` despite the docs saying otherwise. I have solved this issue before. Do see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74663046/user-status-always-returns-offline

Comment: @3nws `ctx.interaction.user.status` seems to give the same results--always returning "offline"

Comment: @Raymus Thank you! I also noticed that fetching the member object through a method like that works as intended. I am glad to know that it is not just me, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this may just be a bug, as there is nothing inherently wrong with the code (according to the docs). A work-around would be to access the desired member through using `guild.get_member()` which always returns a functioning `discord.Member` object.